# Why is there a change in entropy in a irreversible isothermic process?

Tags: thermodynamics

Suppose you have a irreversible isothermal process. The net change in entropy from the system to the surroundings should be 0 if the temperature does not change. So why is there an increase in entropy? Is it because in only an ideal situation you would be able to keep the temperature constant? Does fluctuation cause $\Delta Q/T$ to increase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We note the existence of an irreversible, isothermal thermodynamic process during which the entropy increases which is an explicit counterexample to your claim that

> The net change in entropy from the system to the surroundings should be 0 if the temperature does not change.

Consider a classical ideal gas initially confined by a partition to one half of a rigid, thermally insulated container by a partition.  If one drills a hole in the partition, then the gas will freely expand to fill the entire container.  Since the container is insulated, the heat transferred to the gas is zero during this process, $Q=0$, and since the gas expanded freely, no work is done on the gas, $W=0$, so by the First Law of Thermodynamics, the change in internal energy of the gas is zero, $\Delta U = 0$.  It follows that since $U=cNk_BT $ for a classical ideal gas, and since the particle number of the gas does not change during this process: $\Delta T = 0$.  This process is also irreversible and is accompanied by a positive change in entropy $Nk_B\ln 2$.

No consideration of fluctuations is necessary.

Comment: So what determines whether or not a isothermic process is reversible or non-reversible?

Comment: @notorious If the entropy of an isolated system increases (as in the counterexample I give above), then the process is irreversible because the reverse process would have strictly decreasing entropy, and the Second Law of Thermodynamics tells us that the entropy of an isolated system can never decrease.

Comment: I understand that entropy is behind this, but what I'm trying to ask is what causes entropy to increase in an irreversible isothermic process, but not in a reversible isotherm process? Why is maintaining in equilibrium important important in order for a process to be reversible?

Comment: @notorious Your assertion that entropy does not increase in a reversible, isothermal process is false.  Consider an ideal gas in a metal cylinder with piston in thermal contact with a heat bath.  If the piston is pulled out slowly, the entropy of the gas will increase since $T dS = \delta Q >0$, and the proces is reversible.  It sounds like maybe your real question might be whether a process being an equilibrium process (aka quasistatic) is necessary for reversibility?

Comment: @notorious I want to say that it *is* necessary, and I'm certain I've seen that assertion made in at least one book, but after some thought, I cannot prove it I'm sorry to say.  You may wish to re-post that as a separate question if that's what you meant to ask, it not at all clear from the original statement of the question.